# Error in Conditional UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements, union

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT        MONTH(data) AS MES, cor, CASE month(data) 
                          WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro' WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro' WHEN 3 THEN 'Março' WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio' WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho' WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho' WHEN
                          8 THEN 'Agosto' WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro' WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro' WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro' WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro' END AS MESCOR, COUNT(*) 
                          AS Expr1, CASE cor WHEN 'AM' THEN '2' WHEN 'VD' THEN '1' WHEN 'VM' THEN '3' END AS Expr2 

FROM            TBINICIATIVAS_PREVISTAS
WHERE        (login ='xxxxxxx')
GROUP BY MONTH(data), cor

UNION 
SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'1' 

UNION
SELECT '1', 'AM', 'Janeiro',0,'2' 

UNION
SELECT '1', 'VM', 'Janeiro',0,'3'


ORDER BY expr2, mes
```

---

But I need the `UNION` to be conditional.
Something like:

```
if (select count(*) .... where cond1...) = 0
UNION 
SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'1' 

if (select  count(*) ....where cond2...) = 0
UNION
SELECT '1', 'AM', 'Janeiro',0,'2'

if (select  count(*) ....where cond3...) = 0
UNION
SELECT '1', 'VM', 'Janeiro',0,'3'
```

I tried, but I always got a syntax error.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the error message and if possible also the table structure with some sample data: preferably within a sql fiddle.

Comment: AND, your sql language

Comment: I use SQLSERVER 2012

Comment: The error is that I can´t execute because the "UNION" is underlined with red. I think is a syntax error

Comment: The error is "Incorrect syntax near UNION"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your conditions to a `WHERE` clause inside each `UNION`'s `SELECT` (you can't put anything other than a `SELECT` between `UNION`).

```
SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'0'

UNION 

SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'1' 
WHERE (select  count(*) ....where cond1...) = 0

UNION

SELECT '1', 'AM', 'Janeiro',0,'2'
WHERE (select  count(*) ....where cond2...) = 0

UNION

SELECT '1', 'VM', 'Janeiro',0,'3'
WHERE (select  count(*) ....where cond3...) = 0
```

Also, I note from your conditions that you are checking if the row exists, by doing a `count = 0`. Replacing this with an actual `NOT EXISTS` will be faster because the SQL engine doesn't have to actually count all rows to compare against 0, it will return immediately when a row is found.

```
SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'0'

UNION 

SELECT '1', 'VD', 'Janeiro',0,'1' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select  1 ....where cond1...)

UNION

SELECT '1', 'AM', 'Janeiro',0,'2'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select  1 ....where cond2...)

UNION

SELECT '1', 'VM', 'Janeiro',0,'3'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select  1 ....where cond3...)
```